# Optimal contour shape for variational problem over captured area

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

Let's assume we have a continuous and finite scalar function $f(x,y)$ over the $xy$ plane ($\mathbb{R}^{2}$) and this function is to be integrated over a bounded  area (surface) $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$, which represents a subdomain on the same $xy$ plane, as $\int_{A} f(x,y) dA$. And let the area be nonzero, or perhaps even a constant area $A=A_{0}$. Then, it is clear that the **shape** of this area, as defined by the contour enclosing it (call it $g(x,y)=0)$, will influence the result of the integral.

The question now is what is the contour shape for this area that would extremize this integral? How to express the variational problem correctly (well posed) to be in terms of the contour shape?

This question is the core behind a variation problem I am trying to formulate. My attempted formulation (reported here: [Formulation of contour variational problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281095/formulation-of-contour-variational-problem)) is having difficulty producing a reasonable answer in the form of independent Euler-Lagrange equations. Probably it is ill posed somewhere, but I cannot find why/how. Any insight or advice on how to formulate it would be helpful.

(Note, this bears some similarity to Queen Dido's classical variational problem, but here we are are not restricting the contour perimeter -- rather we require nonzero (or fixed) area, and we have a function $f$ as the integrand in the area integral).

Comment: Do you mean $A = \{(x,y) : f(x,y) > m\}$ for an appropriate $m$?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I think you are saying that $f$ is being restricted in some way over $A$, but this is not the case. $f(x,y)$ has no such restrictions, and can take any variation, as long as it is continuous. $A$ is an area in the physical sense, and therefore is non-negative. However, the problem will become trivial if we allow $A=0$, therefore, we added the restriction that $A>0$, or that $A$ is a fixed constant (call it $A_{0}$).

Comment: If you don't impose *some* condition on the boundary (such as fixed length, etc.) then, obviously, the functional will have no critical points (as long as $f$ is positive), so there won't be an associated Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, but: (1) $f$ is not necessarily positive, and (2) shouldn't the constraint of fixed area be enough (why does it have to be a constraint on the boundary itself?)? As you can see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281095/formulation-of-contour-variational-problem   I have tried to constrain the area, but still got two Euler-Lagrange equations that were not independent, and simply implying that the associate Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ is zero. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: @user135626: If your question is "for what kind of set $A$ with a given area the integral $\iint_A f$ is maximal", then the answer is: super-level set $A = \{(x,y) : f(x,y) > m\}$ for an appropriate $m$. I apologise if I misunderstand the problem.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki If I understand you correcntly, I think the "super-level curve" given in your answer is a solution to the question "what is the set of points that make $f>m$", rather than "what is the set of points that make $I:=\iint_{A} f dA$ stationary". Note that we are trying to make the derivate of $I$ with respect to contour shape (i.e. set boundary) go to zero (not simply the derivative with respect to area, $A$).

Comment: @RobertBryant Sorry, there is a mistake in my comment above: it should say "... the associated Lagrange multiplier $\lambda=f$".

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thinking more about your suggestion, I am starting to see your point, but: I guess the question will be how to choose the appropriate $m$ in practice? For maximizing the integral, we can keep lowering $m$ and it will let the set gradually include all points $(x,y)$ as we get below the lowest point $(x_{0},y_{0}):f(x_{0},y_{0})=f_{min}$ and $A$ may then include all the plane on which $f$ is defined. But if the set's total area is to be fixed to finite value $A_{0}$, then how do we find the appropriate $m$ then?

Comment: @user135626: Well, there is no algebraic expression unless you know $f$ explicitly. And if you ask about numerical methods, any standard method (bisection, Newton's iteration) will do, depending on regularity of $f$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki This confirms my fear that this approach is perhaps not variational in the classical analytical sense that would lead to some more specific analytic answer. It is not easy to incorporate into it further constraints analytically. But thanks anyway :)